# How to update specific element's value in xml using TSql?

Tags: sql, t-sql

My script can only find first match and updates it but I want to update record where it matches id. Here is my sample xml :-

```
    create table catalog
(
catalog xml
);
Insert into catalog
select '<catalog>
   <book> 
      <id>1</id>
      <read>true</read>
   </book>
   <book> 
      <id>2</id>
      <read>true</read>
   </book>
   <book> 
      <id>3</id>
      <read>true</read>
   </book>
   <book> 
      <id>4</id>
      <read>true</read>
   </book>
   </catalog>'
```

I am using this script to modify value of one element:-

```
UPDATE catalog
SET catalog.modify('replace value of (/catalog/book/read/text())[1] with "false"')
WHERE catalog.value('(/catalog/book/id/text())[1]','int') = 3
```

This script does update record when I used id = 1 but unable to update for Id 2,3 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some element that identify individual book nodes I think we could use replace.

```
--Replace could work if your id were and element of book
/*
  <book id="3">   
    <read>true</read>
  </book>*/

--This query only work for the XML above 
UPDATE catalog_tbl
SET [catalog].modify('replace value of 
(/catalog/book/id[@id=("3")]/read/text())[1] with ("false")')
go
```

Instead, if delete and insert is acceptable update approach to you the script below will work.

```
--delete your node first
UPDATE catalog_tbl
SET [catalog].modify('delete (/catalog/book)[3]')

--then insert the element back with read=false
UPDATE catalog_tbl
SET [catalog].modify('insert <book><id>3</id><read>false</read></book> into (/catalog)[1]')
go
```